# compare df1 column 1 to all columns in df2 returning the index of df2

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm new to pandas so likely overlooking something but I've been searching and haven't found anything helpful yet.

What I'm trying to do is this. I have 2 dataframes. `df1` has only 1 column and an unknown number of rows. `df2` has an unknown number of rows also and also an unknown number of columns for each index.

```
Example:
df1:
0     1117454
1     1147637
2     1148945
3     1149662
4     1151543
5     1151545
6     1236268
7     1236671
8     1236673
...
300   1366962

df2:
                1        2        3        4        5        6        7  
8302813476  1375294  1375297  1375313  1375318  1375325  1375330  1375331   
8302813477  1317422  1363270  1363288  1363262     None     None     None   
8302813478  1187269  1187276  1149662  1147843  1147639  1236650  1236656
```

So what I want is to check all `df1` values against `df2` column 1 - n and if there is a match with any value in `df1` mark the index of `df2` as True else it is False.

Comment: Can you add desired output? Can you explain `mark the index of df2 as True else it is False` ?

Comment: df2.stack().isin(df1.squeeze()).unstack()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) for testing matching of `Series` created from `df2` by [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) with `Series` created from one column `df1` by [`squeeze`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.squeeze.html). Last reshape by [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html):

```
df3 = df2.stack().isin(df1.squeeze()).unstack()
print (df3)
                1      2      3      4      5      6      7
8302813476  False  False  False  False  False  False  False
8302813477  False  False  False  False  False  False  False
8302813478  False  False   True  False  False  False  False
```

Then get find all values where at least one `True` by [`any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html):

```
a = df3.any(axis=1)
print (a)
8302813476    False
8302813477    False
8302813478     True
dtype: bool
```

And last [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
print (a[a].index)
Int64Index([8302813478], dtype='int64')
```

Another solution is instead `squeeze` use `df1['col'].unique()`, thank you [Ted Petrou](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41178415/compare-df1-column-1-to-all-columns-in-df2-returning-the-index-of-df2/41179004#comment69558023_41179004):

```
df3 = df2.stack().isin(df1['col'].unique()).unstack()
print (df3)
                1      2      3      4      5      6      7
8302813476  False  False  False  False  False  False  False
8302813477  False  False  False  False  False  False  False
8302813478  False  False   True  False  False  False  False
```

### ---

I like `squeeze` more, but same output is simple selecting column of `df1`:

```
df3 = df2.stack().isin(df1['col']).unstack()
print (df3)
                1      2      3      4      5      6      7
8302813476  False  False  False  False  False  False  False
8302813477  False  False  False  False  False  False  False
8302813478  False  False   True  False  False  False  False
```

Comment: Why is `squeeze` necessary? Can't you change `df1.squeeze()` to `df1['col'].unique()`? Or does `isin` take care of uniqueness under the hood?

Comment: Yes, it is another solution, I think faster.

Comment: exactly. isin do uniqueness, but then solution is slowier.

Comment: @TedPetrou I think squeeze is convenient in answering questions when it's unclear what the OP has.  I've seen posters say they had a DataFrame when it was a Series and if it was a DataFrame I don't know what the column name is.  I could do `df.iloc[:, 0]` but I think that's ugly sometimes.

Comment: Ok thanks. that makes sense. It just looked bizarre. Was wondering what I was missing.

Answer (score 3):

As an interesting numpy alternative

```
l1 = df1.values.ravel()
l2 = df2.values.ravel()

pd.DataFrame(
    np.equal.outer(l1, l2).any(0).reshape(df2.values.shape),
    df2.index, df2.columns
)
```

or using `set`, `list` and comprehension

```
l1 = set(df1.values.ravel().tolist())
l2 = df2.values.ravel().tolist()

pd.DataFrame(
    np.array([bool(l1.intersection([d])) for d in l2]).reshape(df2.values.shape),
    df2.index, df2.columns
)
```

[image]